# ZXing Android Generate 1D barcode

Tags: android, mobile, barcode, zxing, barcode-scanner

I've gone through the examples here regarding encoding barcode:

http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/androidtest/src/com/google/zxing/client/androidtest/ZXingTestActivity.java

But all it generates are QR.  I'm looking for **1D barcode generation / encoding**.  What's the right encode type?

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");
intent.setPackage("com.google.zxing.client.android");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", "???");
```

Barcode Scanner doesn't like ENCODE_TYPE = CODE_39 nor CODE_93.  Any ideas?

Comment: Could you solved?. I have to do the same and I can't understand how to do??

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need the javadoc for [Intents](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/source/browse/trunk/android/src/com/google/zxing/client/android/Intents.java). You need `ENCODE_FORMAT`, not `ENCODE_TYPE`.

Answer (score 7):

## To encode/generate 1D barcode

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.ENCODE");

intent.putExtra("ENCODE_FORMAT", "UPC_A");
intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", "12345678901");

startActivity(intent);
```

The key here is **ENCODE_FORMAT** & the 1D barcode format in this case **UPC_A** & the data (for UPC code it has to be 11/12 digits) to encode

Hope this helps