# Create/Generate Barcode using Zxing on Android

Tags: android, barcode, zxing

I need to write an android aplication to create/generate a barcode using a string with the value to show.

The android app had to show a pic with the barcode to be scaned with other phone.

I read a lot from internet and everybody recomend to use Zxing for that, but i can't find some tutorial about how to use Zxing to create barcodes on android.

I have experince using Zxing with Android-Integration to read QR Code.

I have to use the same to create barcode?

Can i use Android-Integration?

Thank you very much
Sorry for my poor english

Comment: Another part for my question. Is posible to generate 1D Barcode with Zxing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scanning via `Intent` should be all you need: https://github.com/zxing/zxing/wiki/Scanning-Via-Intent

Comment: Yes, that part is the Read part. But my problem es how to Generate/Create the code from my app made with Java for Android.

Comment: Ah right. This is what you want then: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6376400/zxing-android-generate-1d-barcode

Comment: Yes, but I can't understand what to do. In my project Im using IntentIntegrator and IntentResult. Do I need something else?. Thanks

Comment: Finally I made it work, but know when I test with ENCODE_TYPE:"CODE_128" and ENCODE_DATA:"12345" give me "Could not encode a barcode from the data provided." Any Idea?

Comment: As my comment on the question says: it's `ENCODE_FORMAT` not `ENCODE_TYPE`

Comment: Yes!, I didn't read that until late, heheh. Thank you very much for your help!